# Find the inverse of the function $f(x) =\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I'm trying to prove a certain integral converges, and for that I need to find the inverse of $f(x) =\dfrac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}$. I've gotten this far:

$x = \dfrac{\ln(y)}{1-y^2} \rightarrow e^x = e^{\left( \frac{\ln(y)}{1-y^2} \right)} = y^{\frac{1}{1-y^2}}$

But I'm stuck here. I know the function should have an inverse but I just can't find it. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Every bijection has an inverse. Doesn't mean the inverse has a "closed form".

Comment: Most functions (even monotone increasing functions) lack convenient inverses.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+z%3Dln%28x%29%2F%28-x%5E2%2B1%29+for+x) is what Wolfram Alpha finds in terms of the W function.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Yeah, and it's weirdly hard to parse.  I read it the same way you did, but maybe they meant $W((2e)^{2z}z)$?  Even so...   Anyway, I agree it looks badly off.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the original integral whose convergence you're trying to prove. There might be better ways of dealing with it than trying to explicitly wrote out the inverse function above.

Comment: @Allawonder I've indeed solved the problem using another method, albeit not as elegant as the one that prompted the question

Answer (score 3):

I am *not* an expert. But, I would go something like the following :

$$\begin{align}&\ln x-y+yx^2=0\\
\iff &\ln x^2-2y+2yx^2=0\end{align}$$

Let  $\thinspace x^2=e^u$ and $2y=z$, then :

$$
\begin{align}u-z+ze^{u}&=0\\
u+\ln z-z+e^{u+\ln z}&=\ln z\\
\end{align}
$$

Then let  $\thinspace u+\ln z=t$, you have :

$$
\begin{align}&t+e^t=z+\ln z\\
\implies &e^{t+e^t}=e^{z+\ln z}\\
\implies &e^te^{e^t}=e^{\ln \left(ze^z\right)}\\
\implies &e^t=W\left(ze^z\right)\\
\implies &u=\ln W\left(ze^z\right) -\ln z\\
\implies &u=\ln \frac {W\left(2ye^{2y}\right)}{2y}\end{align}
$$

Finally, the inverse function becomes : $x=±\sqrt {e^u}$

$$
\begin{align}±\sqrt {\frac {W\left(2xe^{2x}\right)}{2x}}\thinspace . \end{align}
$$

Comment: Perhaps mention that $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: This calculus appears to contain too many exponentiations. After the first you can already start to transform for Lambert-W $(z-u)e^{z-u}=ze^z$. As one has to exclude the singular points $u=0$, $x=\pm 1$, one has to use different branches of the Lambert-W function, like $u=z-W_{-1}(ze^z)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, especially for the last points .  When we find $u$ in terms of $\ln$, the inverse function becomes *simpler*, since the last expression has *no exponent*.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly I've yet to learn about the Lambert $W$ function, I'll come back to this when I do.